# Notification content text being changed based on different scenarios

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

I am building  an app which shows notification when a new message arrives.I have successfully implemented the notification part-but there, I am facing some weird issue while viewing my shown notifications -it is showing different content text based on different scenarios-I am including the 2 cases-

a)when the notifications arrives

b)when I slide down the notification tray to see my notifications

[image]      [image]

As you can clearly see the differences in the content-text in two different cases- Why is it happening ?

I am attaching the code which I have implemented to build the notifications-

```
   @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    String identifyDataType = remoteMessage.getData().get(getString(R.string.data_type));
    //SITUATION: Application is in foreground then only send priority notificaitons such as an admin notification
    Log.d(TAG, "Data type: data: " +identifyDataType);

    if(identifyDataType.equals(getString(R.string.data_type_admin_broadcast))){
        //build admin broadcast notification
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get(getString(R.string.data_title));
        String senderId=remoteMessage.getData().get(getString(R.string.sender_of_message));
        String message = remoteMessage.getData().get(getString(R.string.data_message));
        Log.d(TAG,"TITL AND MESSG"+title+message);
        sendBroadcastNotification(title, message,senderId);
    }
}



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void sendBroadcastNotification(String title, String message, String senderId){
    Log.d(TAG, "sendBroadcastNotification: building a admin broadcast notification with  "+title+" "+message);

    NotificationChannel mChannel=null;
    // Instantiate a Builder object.
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "default_channel_id");
    // Creates an Intent for the Activity
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notifyIntent.putExtra("Id", "none");
    Log.d("messsagingService Title",title);
    notifyIntent.putExtra("Name", title.split(":")[1].trim());
    // Sets the Activity to start in a new, empty task
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    // Creates the PendingIntent
    PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this,
                    0,
                    notifyIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mChannel = new NotificationChannel("default_channel_id", getString(R.string.app_name), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    // Configure the notification channel.
    mChannel.setDescription(message);
    mChannel.enableLights(true);
    mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
    mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

    //add properties to the builder
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icons1)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                    R.drawable.icons1))
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_btn_bg_color))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(title).setSummaryText(message))
            .setNumber(mNumPendingMessages)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

    builder.setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent);



    mNotificationManager.notify(BROADCAST_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

}
```

Any help is very much solicited -why this is even happening! Thank you.